# Extjs 5.1.1 can't modify padding or margin values in Layout: 'table'

Tags: css, extjs

I'm having some elements added inside a panel that uses 'talbe' as it's layout

```
xtype:'panel',
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 2,
}
```

After added some stuff, I noticed when I'm using 'padding' or 'margin', distance could be easily changed on both 'Left' & 'Right' side. 
However, no matter whatever value I give, the 'top' and 'bottom' distance just won't change at all.

Tried stuff from Sencha doc file and some other Google resources, none of them works. I list some options I used below

```
//1
// margin: '20 0 50 0', // Top Right Bottom Left

//2
// padding: '20px 0px 50px 0px', // Top Right Bottom Left

//3
// style:'margin-top: 155px;',

//4
// style:'padding-top: 155px;',
```

None of these works.
Besides that, I saw some other people saying we should modify 'tableAttrs' and 'tdAttrs'. I tried these with all 4 above, still the same.

so 2 questions:

1. Is there another thing we should set to enable modifying top and bottom value?
2. What is preferred when trying to change the distance between elements inside a same container? Padding or margin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Youv'e asked just 1 question mate

Comment: can you add a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com) ?

Comment: Not enough code, you should always provide code that we can run. You should use CSS by the way instead of setting padding with JavaScript. The easiest way is to give your Component a `cls` and use that to style it with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the below example. Here I have used padding inside an item of a panel with table layout. It is working fine. Please try it and let me know the results.

similar result will come if you use margin also. So anything can be used in this case. But padding is preferred generally.

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        title: 'Table Layout',
        width: 300,
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            columns: 2
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'component',
            html: 'Cell A content',
            cls: 'a',
            rowspan: 2,
            padding: '50 0 20 10'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            html: 'Cell B content',
            cls: 'b',
            colspan: 2,
            margin: '50 0'
        }, {
            xtype: 'component',
            html: 'Cell C content',
            cls: 'c',
            padding: '50 0'
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Here's a fiddle that shows padding/margin on the components:

[https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/138v](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/138v%20fiddle)

For Cell B, it has margin of 50px on top/bottom, you'll have to inspect that component to see such but the margins are there. Cell C has 50px top/bottom padding. This is the difference between margin and padding and how it affects that component.Thanks Mitchell for your suggestion.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your responding. I tried, but it still appear as I described above. 'Left' and 'right' change will work perfectly but no matter what value I give for North/Top or South/Bottom. it will just stay where the element is (lable)

Comment: Joe I have edited my answer above to add a fiddle with clear explanation. Please check.

Comment: Hi, really appreciate your help, unfortunately it still won't change. I moved my eyes somewhere else and trying to see maybe some other setting(s) is/are blocking us from modifying stuff here

Comment: Please post the code of the view so that I can help